# Counting the repetition of an element of an array java

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

I need to count the frequency of an element in arrays.
I used the method

```
Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arr),element);
```

but I get zero all the times
any ideas ?!

Comment: Show us your actual code: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's the type of element? What's the type of arr?

Comment: What objects are in the list? Are equals and hashCode properly overriden?

Comment: I have an idea, that you should show us YOUR code ;) We are not going to proviide you a fresh code. Even if you could easily find one with Google

Answer (score 1):

If you are `ArrayList` consists of elements of custom `type`

example person bean, or employee object.

Make sure you have overridden `equals()` method and `hash()` methods
if you have not overridden these methods that Collection method wont work.

Comment: could be that or could be that `arr` is an array of primitives.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give details about "arr" & element. However, I did came across this some time back when I tried to use an array of primitives such as int[], converting them to a List using Arrays.asList()

There is nothing like List of "int". An Integer would work however, Integer arr[] = {1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,5,6};